# Creating a circle in pygame with points on circumference

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, geometry, collision-detection

I'm looking to create a circle in pygame that I can move around a space with "sensors" on the edges. I want there to be a "front", "left" and "right" sensor on the circumference, that I can use to manipulate the circle's movements.

Basically, these points are to help detect surrounding obstacles, and allow the circle to be rotated as it moves (to help control movement).

In the image below you can see the idea, the circle starts at a location, has the pointers, and moves around the space and avoids the square obstacle, and I'm able to turn it at various angles without losing sense of what the "front" and "back" of it is.

I don't care if the dots on the circle's edges to identify the "sensors" are seen or not in the overall graphic, just drew and labelled them to illustrate the idea.

Side note: I realize looking at the image that the R and L labels are backwards given the orientation of the circle itself, but still the same idea.

[image: circles]

Comment: Are these "sensors" on the edge of the circle meant to check for collisions, or for getting the orientation of the circle and seeing where the "front" is? If it is the former, if you have the center of the circle, you can calculate the distance from the center to each of the four corners of the rectangle. If the distance between the center and any one of these corners is less than the radius, you know that the circle and rectangle must overlap! If it is the latter, just designate one point as the front in and add 90 degrees CW to get the right or 90 degrees CCW to get the left point.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon It's mainly for getting the orientation of the circle and seeing where the front it, so as to avoid collisions (I'm doing a fuzzy logic implementation, and the way it's set up is that the circle is replicating a robot that would have sensors to see what's around it, and would use the fuzzy rules to avoid its surroundings). If designating what the front point is, is there a way to track this point as the robot/circle is moving through the space? (For instance, I don't want it to always be the most south point or something).

Comment: You probably want to separate the position & bearings of your agent, from its representation as a circle

Comment: @ReblochonMasque can you elaborate on this a bit? (Still consider myself more at a beginner level with some of this)

Comment: I don't see clear question.

Comment: BTW [Pygame homepage recommends to use Python 3.6.1 or newer](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted), just saying

Comment: @Kos If I could get it working for python 3 I would, but after many hours of reinstalling and trying to get it working, for some reasons my mac just woudn't run pygame in python 3, only in 2. I know it has something to do with the paths and default python on my machine, but it wasn't worth the aggravation anymore, so just settled for doing it in 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just define some [vectors](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) for the three points. If you create a vector with the radius of the circle and add it to the center coordinates, you get a point on the circumference. Then you can rotate this vector by -90 and 90 degrees to get the other two vectors. When the agent rotates, you can first rotate the front vector and then use it again to get the left and right vectors.

Here's a complete example:

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Agent(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super(Agent, self).__init__(*groups)
        self.radius = 25
        self.image = pg.Surface((50, 50), pg.SRCALPHA)
        pg.draw.circle(self.image, pg.Color('dodgerblue4'),
                       (self.radius, self.radius), self.radius)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.speed = 0
        self.angular_speed = 0
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)
        # If you add this vector to the center pos, you get a point
        # on the circumference of the circle.
        self.front = Vector2(0, -self.radius)  # Pointing upward.
        # Just rotate the front vector by -90 and 90 degrees to get
        # the left and right vectors. `rotate` returns a new vector.
        self.left = self.front.rotate(-90)
        self.right = self.front.rotate(90)

    def update(self):
        # Use the front vector as the velocity.
        self.pos += self.front.normalize() * self.speed
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        if self.angular_speed != 0:
            self.rotate()

    def rotate(self):
        """Rotate the front vector and use it to update the other two."""
        self.front.rotate_ip(self.angular_speed)
        self.left = self.front.rotate(-90)
        self.right = self.front.rotate(90)

    def draw_vectors(self, screen):
        """Draw the three vectors."""
        pg.draw.circle(screen, (0, 240, 50), list(map(int, self.pos+self.front)), 3)
        pg.draw.circle(screen, (240, 0, 50), list(map(int, self.pos+self.left)), 3)
        pg.draw.circle(screen, (240, 240, 0), list(map(int, self.pos+self.right)), 3)
        pg.draw.line(screen, (0, 240, 50), self.pos, self.pos+self.front, 2)
        pg.draw.line(screen, (240, 0, 50), self.pos, self.pos+self.left, 2)
        pg.draw.line(screen, (240, 240, 0), self.pos, self.pos+self.right, 2)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    agent = Agent((100, 300), all_sprites)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_w:
                    agent.speed = 5
                elif event.key == pg.K_a:
                    agent.angular_speed = -10
                elif event.key == pg.K_d:
                    agent.angular_speed = 10
            elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_w:
                    agent.speed = 0
                elif event.key == pg.K_a:
                    agent.angular_speed = 0
                elif event.key == pg.K_d:
                    agent.angular_speed = 0

        all_sprites.update()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        agent.draw_vectors(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Concept question, what exactly is the difference/benefit to using the sprite class for objects vs. simply using pygame.draw.circle?

Comment: Also, booted up your code to see how it works and omg you beautiful human thank you!! It looks so cool (idk if that means I'm impressed by simple things, if this is simple for you, or just exposes how much of a beginner I still am). This is so helpful for learning how to get it working!!!

Comment: Using [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) subclasses and sprite groups is often more convenient. They have methods to automatically remove (`kill`) them from sprite groups and there are some useful collision detection functions in the `sprite` module. They have also been optimized for performance (at least a little).

Comment: I think using sprite objects helps to organize the code in a better way in this case, since you have state and behavior which can be bundled in one object.
However, you could achieve the same with some other data structures (e.g. lists or dictionaries) and separate functions.

Comment: Another question about the code, what is the use of the rect in the __init__ function? Right now I'm trying to create quadrants that detect what's on the left and right sides of the circle, and the only solution I've found is using the quadrants that rectangles allow. If I could use the rect that's in the __init__ for this purpose, that'd be great! But idk what it's doing, and don't want to mess it up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Pygame blits the `image` of the sprite at the `topleft` coordinates of this [rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), so whenever you update the actual position (`self.pos`), you have to update the position of the rect as well. It's also needed for collision detection if you use the `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` (or `groupcollide`) function. The rect has the same size as the `self.image` because it was created with the [`get_rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) method of the image/surface.